# find items in a text file but show only those that begin with the input letters

Tags: python-3.x

I apologize for my bad english. I'm still learning.
I want to find an item in a text file, a list, but just want to show the items that begin with the letters of the item.

For example, I have the string "amistad" and the text file contains:

```
ballena 
avispa 
avestruz 
miesta
moe
abeja 
bullterrier
```

and want to show only those words that begin with an "a":

```
avispa 
abeja 
avestruz
```

and then, those that begin with an "m"

```
miesta 
moe
```

until reaches the end of "amistad"

I've been trying with a list, and so far I got this:

```
lista = ['avispa', 'abeja', 'avestruz', 'ballena', 'bisonte', 'bullterrier']
for item in lista:
    if item.find("a") != -1:
        print(item)
```

But this print all the words that contain an "a". I want only those that begin with it.
And not in a list but in file text.
Sorry for my english.
Hope can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `startswith` method:

```
lista = ['avispa', 'abeja', 'avestruz', 'ballena', 'bisonte', 'bullterrier']
for item in lista:
    if item.startswith("a"):
        print(item)
```

I think I understand now. You want to iterate 'amistad' and check all the words that start with each letter in turn? Maybe something like this:

```
lista = ['avispa', 'abeja', 'avestruz', 'ballena', 'bisonte', 'bullterrier']
for letter in "amistad"
    for item in lista:
        if item.startswith(letter):
            print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I got this ... 
with open('d:\lista.txt', 'r') as inF: 
b = input(Enter word: ') 
for letter in b: 
 for item in inF: 
  if item.startswith(letter): 
   print(item)

If I type "zucaritas", print only those begining in "z" and not the other letters. What can I do? 
By the way, I'm a beginner in python.
Thanks

Comment: too much code in comments. need thread. experiment with what you've got and start a new thread? You should accept an answer if we've sorted what you need. I'm not really sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = ['avispa', 'abeja', 'avestruz', 'ballena', 'bisonte', 'bullterrier','miesta','moe']
for item in lista: 
    for letter in list("amistad"):
        if item[0] == letter:
            print(item)
```

If you want to take your input from a file, then look up how to use f = open('file.txt',r), read the lines and add each line to your list.